# Could not call my webservice for trust issue in android

Tags: java, android, ssl, soap, https

I wrote a method in android to call my webservice.

```
public void HelloWorld() {
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        Log.e("ali", response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but when I call this function, it return this :

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

how could I fix that
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is described in this site :

https://gelecegiyazanlar.turkcell.com.tr/soru/ksoap2-ile-web-service-erisirken-sslhandshakeexception